# Java regex parse sections of long text

Tags: java, regex

I have a huge txt that can contain several house names and, for each house, there are some values specific to that specific house, and so on. Here is a similar part of my txt:

```
getHouseName: house1
random useless text
price: 1000
squaremtr: 75
sellVal: 1000
random useless text
random useless text
random useless text
rentPrice: 150
getHouseName: house2
price: 1004
squaremtr: 85
sellVal: 950
random useless text
rentPrice: 150
getHouseName: house3
price: 1099
squaremtr: 90
random useless text
random useless text
sellVal: 1100
random useless text
rentPrice: 199
```

I would like, for every house, to retrieve values specific for each house and store them into a variable using regexes. Right now this is my code:

```
public void testHouse() {
    Scanner txt = new Scanner(new File("path//to//file"));

    String houseName ="";
    String price = "";
    String squaremtr = "";
    String sellVal = "";
    String rentPrice = "";
    
    Pattern houseNamePatt = Pattern.compile("getHouseName: ((_!getHouseName: \\s).)*", Pattern.DOTALL);

    while(txt.hasNextLine()) {
        String str = txt.nextLine();
        Matcher m = houseNamePatt.matcher(str);
        if(m.find) {
            houseName=str.substring(m.end());
            System.out.println("houses: " + m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case I'm just getting a list with all the house names, not the lines between each name and I definitely can't assign the values of a specific house to my variables. Where am I wrong?
Thank you

Comment: If you want the variables with the values, you can use capturing groups and use a pattern  to get the values line by line. `getHouseName:\h+(.*)\Rprice:\h+(\d+)` etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all values by matching the names followed by a capturing group. If there are lines in between with random values, you can match all lines that do not start with the next expected value using a negative lookahead `(?!`

Then set the values of the variables equals to the group number.

```
^getHouseName:\h+(.+)(?:\R(?!price:).*)*\Rprice: (\d+)(?:\R(?!squaremtr:).*)*\Rsquaremtr:\h+(\d+)(?:\R(?!sellVal:).*)*\RsellVal:\h+(\d+)(?:\R(?!rentPrice:).*)*\RrentPrice:\h+(\d+)
```

In parts:

- `^` Start of string
- `getHouseName:\h+(.+)` Match the value for *getHouseName* in **group 1**
- `(?:\R(?!price:).*)*\Rprice: (\d+)` Match until the next line with *price*, capture 1+ digits in **group 2**
- `(?:\R(?!squaremtr:).*)*\Rsquaremtr:\h+(\d+)` Match until the next line with *squaremtr*, capture 1+ digits in **group 3**
- `(?:\R(?!sellVal:).*)*\RsellVal:\h+(\d+)` Match until the next line with *sellVal*, capture 1+ digits in **group 4**
- `(?:\R(?!rentPrice:).*)*\RrentPrice:\h+(\d+)` Match until the next line with *rentPrice*, capture 1+ digits in **group 5**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/om4359/1)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will do it:

```
(?m)^getHouseName: (.*)\\Rprice: (.*)\\Rsquaremtr: (.*)\\RsellVal: (.*)\\RrentPrice: (.*)
```

*Test*

```java
String hugeText = "getHouseName: house1\n" + 
                  "price: 1000\n" + 
                  "squaremtr: 75\n" + 
                  "sellVal: 1000\n" + 
                  "rentPrice: 150\n" + 
                  "getHouseName: house2\n" + 
                  "price: 1004\n" + 
                  "squaremtr: 85\n" + 
                  "sellVal: 950\n" + 
                  "rentPrice: 150\n" + 
                  "getHouseName: house3\n" + 
                  "price: 1099\n" + 
                  "squaremtr: 90\n" + 
                  "sellVal: 1100\n" + 
                  "rentPrice: 199";

String regex = "(?m)^" +
               "getHouseName: (.*)\\R" + 
               "price: (.*)\\R" + 
               "squaremtr: (.*)\\R" + 
               "sellVal: (.*)\\R" + 
               "rentPrice: (.*)";
for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(hugeText); m.find(); ) {
    String houseName = m.group(1);
    String price     = m.group(2);
    String squaremtr = m.group(3);
    String sellVal   = m.group(4);
    String rentPrice = m.group(5);
    System.out.printf("%-8s %6s %4s %6s %5s%n",
                      houseName, price, squaremtr, sellVal, rentPrice);
}
```

*Output*

```
house1     1000   75   1000   150
house2     1004   85    950   150
house3     1099   90   1100   199
```

Comment: I modified my question, because I have some random text between the values. How can I modify that according to the complex text?

Comment: @thranduil90 Please be more accurate when asking. Are the 5 values you're always present, and are they always in the same order? Make sure question has the full specification of what you're looking for.